# perl dbi mysql - value precision

Tags: mysql, linux, perl, rounding, dbi

**user@host:~#** `mysql -V` - mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25-28, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  7.0 running under debian-9,9

**user@host:~#** `uname -a` - Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3.1 (2019-02-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

**user@host:~#** `perl -MDBI -e 'print $DBI::VERSION ."\n";'` - 1.636

**user@host:~#** `perl -v` This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 1 (v5.24.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

**mysql>** `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl1;`

```
tbl1 | CREATE TABLE `tbl1` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `main_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `debet` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `kurs` double(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `summ` double(20,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `is_sync` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `main_id` (`main_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=70013000018275 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**mysql>** `SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE id=70003020040132;`

```
-+---------------+----------------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
| id             | main_id        | debet | kurs   | summ    | is_sync | 
+----------------+----------------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
| 70003020040132 | 70003020038511 |       | 0.0000 | 1798.00 | 0       |
+----------------+----------------+-------+--------+---------+---------+
```

But when I get this data by perl::DBI module I lose precisions, and values `0.0000` and `1798.00` becomes `0` and `1798`.

Code is next:

```
#### 
#These 3 subs are connecting to DB, executing query and get data by fetchall_arrayref and coverting undef to NULL.
####
sub DB_connect {
    # DataBase Handler
    my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$DBNAME", $DBUSER, $DBPWD,{RaiseError => 0, PrintError => 0, mysql_enable_utf8 => 1}) or die "Error connecting to database: $DBI::errstr";
    return $dbh;
}
sub DB_executeQuery {
    # Executes SQL query. Return reference to array, or array, according to argv[0]
    # argv[0] - "A" returns array, "R" - reference to array
    # argv[1] - DB handler from DB_connect
    # argv[2] - query to execute

    my $choice=shift @_;
    my $dbh=shift @_;
    my $query=shift @_;
    print "$query\n" if $DEBUG>2;
    my $sth=$dbh->prepare($query) or die "Error preparing $query for execution: $DBI::errstr";
    $sth->execute;
    my $retval = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;

    if ($choice eq "A" ) {
    my @ret_arr=();
    foreach my $value (@{ $retval }) {
        push @ret_arr,@{ $value };
    }
    return @ret_arr;
    }
    elsif ($choice eq "R") {
    return $retval;
    }
}

sub undef2null {
    # argv[1] - reference ro array of values where undef
    # values has to be changed to NULL
    # Returns array of prepared values: (...) (...) ...
    my $ref=shift @_;
    my @array=();
    foreach my $row (@{ $ref }) {
    my $str="";
    foreach my $val ( @{ $row} ) {
        if (! defined ( $val )) {
        $str="$str, NULL";
        }
        else {
        # Escape quotes and other symbols listed in square brackets
        $val =~ s/([\"\'])/\\$1/g; 
        $str="$str, \'$val\'";
        }
    }
    # Remove ', ' at the beginning of each VALUES substring
    $str=substr($str,2);
    push @array,"($str)";
    } # End foreach my $row (@{ $ref_values })
    return @array;
} # End undef2null

#### Main call
#...
# Somewhere in code I get data from DB and print it to out file
my @arr_values=();
my @arr_col_names=DB_executeQuery("A",$dbh,qq(SELECT column_name FROM `information_schema`.`columns` WHERE `table_schema` = '$DBNAME' AND `table_name` = '@{ $table }'));
@arr_ids=DB_executeQuery("A",$dbh,qq(SELECT `id` FROM `@{ $table }` WHERE `is_sync`=0));
my $ref_values=DB_executeQuery("R",$dbh,"SELECT * FROM \`@{ $table }\` WHERE \`id\` IN(".join(",",@arr_ids).")");
        @arr_values=undef2null($ref_values);
print FOUT  "REPLACE INTO \`@{ $table }\` (`".join("`, `",@arr_col_names)."`) VALUES  ".(join ", ",@arr_values).";\n";
```

and as a result I get next string:

```
REPLACE INTO `pko_plat` (`id`, `main_id`, `debet`, `kurs`, `summ`, `is_sync`) VALUES  ('70003020040132', '70003020038511', '', '0', '1798', '0')
```

in DB it was `0.0000` - become `0`, was `1798.00`, become `1798`

Perl's DBI documentation says it gets data 'as is' into strings, no translations made. But, then, who rounded values?

Comment: Try insert 1798.00001, what does DBI display now? Does it round the value?

Comment: Shortly - yes, it rounds. I've tested - round happens when getting data from DB by DBI. Not by some other data manipulation methods I use. For example, if I feed MySQL 1798.6356 it rounds to 1798.64 and DBI gets 1798.64. If 1798.00001 - MySQL shows 1798.00 and DBI shows 1798 But I do need 1798.00, the same way as it is in MySQL is shown.

Comment: hmm.. Can't you just postprocess it then:  `$var = sprintf "%.2f\n", $var` ?

Comment: OFC sprintf prints 1798.00. Roundation is done directly when I get data from MySQL using DBI. And the main question is: can I somehow avoid maipulation with numbers when using DBI and simply get all data as strings (as wrote in DBI docs)?

Comment: Sorry, from your comment above it seemed to me it was MySQL (not DBI) that rounded 1798.6356 to 1798.64?

Comment: Re "*I lose precision*", uh, no you don't. You get exactly the number stored in the DB. You are asking how to format the number as the `mysql` client does. DBI does provide ways of querying information about the field, which would allow you to build a format string for `sprintf`, or you could just hardcode it (`sprintf("%.2f", $n)`).

Comment: You might be able to convince the mysql server to perform the conversion for you by requesting a string (by binding parameters or by adjusting the `SELECT` to cast the number to a string).

Comment: Thanks, ikegami, you're right - I just reading about DBI binding and thinking if it can help me. Or, maybe something like CAST, or STR in queries...

Answer (score 1):

The rounding you see is happening because of the way you create the columns.

```sql
  `kurs` double(20,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000'
  `summ` double(20,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00'
```

If you look at the [mysql floating point type documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html) you will see that you are using the non-standard syntax `double(m, d)`, where the two parameters define how the float is being output.

So in your case the values stored in `summ` will be displayed with 2 digits behind the point. This means that when perl gets a value out of the table which is 1.0001 in the database, the value that perl gets delivered by the database is rounded to the set number of digits (in this case .00).

Perl in turn interprets this value ("1.00") as a float, and when printed, will not show any trailing zeroes. If you want these you should accommodate for this in your output.

For example: `print sprintf("%.2f\n", $summ);`

The way I see it you have two ways you can go (if you want to avoid this loss of precision):

- Only add numbers with the correct precision to the database (so for `'summ'` only two trailing digits, and four for `'kurs'`.)
- Alter your table creation to the standard syntax for floats and determine the output formatting in Perl (which you will be doing either way):

```
`kurs` double() NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all for info and help. This question about getting data with DBI and rounding occurs 'cause we already have Python script doing things, and it gets data the SAME as mysql client shows ('0.00' shows as '0.00', not '0'). I DON'T know, how our another applications (C#, PHP, etc) will work with  this "rounded" data (greetings to our developers!). So I tried to create the same behavior with DBI.

Comment: Do you have any insights in how this python script handles the data from the database? Maybe it's never converting it to a numeric type in the first place?

Comment: The way this table is configured, you will always get the formatted, rounded value back unless the databaseconnector has a way of getting the float directly. Also, this way of setting floating point types in mysql (with defining the output) is deprecated, so switching to standard syntax in your table creation really is the better option.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python at all, but have source codes of this script. And found next code: `def make_query_head(self):
        self.query_head = "REPLACE INTO `{0}` ({1}) VALUES ".format(
            self.table, ", ".join(map(lambda x: "`%s`" % x, self.fields))
        )` - here it seems to make convertion?

Comment: Could you post the python code where the data is getting fetched from the database? Looks to me like the fetched data is never converted into a corresponding numeric type. The python code `print("%s" % (2.0000))` would print `2.0`, so either you never had two trailing zeroes, or the value is a string at the moment of output.